# Powershell cannot find element

Tags: javascript, powershell

I'm trying to login, then navigate to a page, then set element values on the second page and submit them. But powershell keeps saying the elements don't exist. So to troubleshoot, I want to write to a text file the contents of the page I'm on. The below script creates a file that is blank. Any ideas?

```
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.visible=$true
$ie.navigate($URL) 


while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) 
{ 
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000; 
} 
$ie.Document.getElementById("userId").value = $username 
$ie.Document.getElementByID("userPassword").value=$password 
$ie.Document.getElementById("login").Click();
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 1; } 


Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 10000; 


#$ie.Document.getElementById("officeList").action ="edit.jsp";
#$ie.Document.getElementById("officeId").value="1234";
#$ie.Document.getElementById("officeList").submit();
$ie.navigate($URL2) 
$ie.document.documentelement.innertext |out-file C:\Users\me\Documents\PowerShell\html.txt
```

Comment: Have you debugged this?  I'd set a break point on `Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 10000` and see what the actual browser window looks like.  Likewise, after the `$ie.navigate($URL2)` call, what does the browser windows look like?

Comment: Yes I watch the IE window and it has content.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure your element is called userId and userPassword etc? You can inspect them when pressing F12 in your browser

Comment: In future please note this is not an answer to the question and should be a comment

Comment: Ah first comment here.. didn't know. I have made something just like this:
$IE = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application;

$IE.visible = $true;
$IE.navigate($url2);
$ie.fullscreen = $true;
start-sleep -s 3
$IE.Document.getElementById("login_username").value=$username2 
$IE.Document.getElementByID("login_password").value=$password2
start-sleep -s 1 
$IE.Document.getElementById("Login").submit()

Comment: I also had the same errors, solved mine with the start-sleeps. I had to tweak them to get it just right. 
The site was loading to slow..